# How to send messages to another apps in Android?

Tags: android, background-music

I want to program a music controller in my app, so I would be able to play/pause, nextSong and previousSong my playlist from another build-in music app. I've seen solution using Broadcast sending messages to all music players to for example start playing music. The problem is, music starts playing on three different music players I have installed. Does anybody know what to use instead of sendBroadcast, so that message will be send only to app I want?

This solution I found on the internet. It uses sendBroadcast() function. The message is broadcasted to every music player which I do not want. I want it to be sent only to one specific app

```java
long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

/*NEXT*/
Intent downIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null);
KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, 
    KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS, 0);
downIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, downEvent);
sendBroadcast(downIntent, null);

Intent upIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null);
KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, 
    KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS, 0);
upIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, upEvent);
sendBroadcast(upIntent, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, declare the receiver in the menifest file :

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.pkg.perform.Ruby" />
    </intent-filter>
```

in my case I have used like this :

```
   final Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.pkg.perform.Ruby");
intent.putExtra("KeyName","code1id");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setComponent(  
    new ComponentName("com.pkg.AppB","com.pkg.AppB.MyBroadcastReceiver"));  
sendBroadcast(intent);
```